# Regex for ??? (three adjacent question marks) codetag for use in PyCharm

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, regex-group

I am trying to utilize [PEP 350 -- Codetags](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/) more in my Python code.

My IDE is PyCharm and I am currently expanding the `TODO` comment regex.  It's found in the `TODO` menu (`Preferences > Editor > TODO`).  The default PyCharm regex used word boundary `\b`.

I have currently expanded it to: `\b(todoc*|fixme|caveat|see)\b.*`

I have been playing around using regex 101, but for the life of me can't find a way to capture the following code tags:

- `???` (question)
- `!!!` (alert)

**edit: someone asked in the comments if I would like to match the end of a word with the special characters (ex: `foo!!!`).  I would not, normally the comment will look like `!!! some information`.

**edit 2: code tags may be followed with a colon (ex: `TODO:`, `CAVEAT:`), so the regex should be flexible in that regards.

---

**What I Have Tried**

[Regex for three dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021352/regex-for-three-dots)

- `\b(todoc*|fixme|caveat|see|\?\?\?)\b.*`
- And more similar permutations involving quotes and double slashes, none worked so far

---

**Versions**

- PyCharm 2020.1 PE

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:todo|fixme|caveat|todoc|see|\?\?\?)(?!\S).*`

Comment: Did you want just `???` and `!!!` alone? Or at the end of the word such as: `foo!!!`?

Comment: Okay @SpencerWieczorek updated my question.  Yes `???` or `!!!` alone, or maybe followed with a colon as sometimes other people use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(\b(todoc*|fixme|caveat|see)\b|\?\?\?|!!!).*`

Answer (score 2):

In stead of using word boundaries `\b` you could use whitespace boundaries and add `|!!!` to the alternation.

```
(?<!\S)((?:todo[ :]|(?:fixme|caveat|todoc|see|[?]{3}|!!!)(?!\S))).*
```

In parts, that will match

- `(?<!\S)` Whitespace boundary to the left
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group
  - `todo[ :]` Match todo followed by a space or `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:fixme|caveat|todoc|see|[?]{3}|!!!)(?!\S)` Match any of the alternaties followed by a whitespace boundary on the right
  - `)` Close non capture group
- `)` Close capture group
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eddw9f/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @TheFourthBird.  I didn't forsee this answer, so I didn't mention that `TODO` comments may be followed with a colon `:` or with whitespace.  The current answer using whitespace boundaries doesn't match when someone writes `TODO:`.  Would you mind adjusting?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer I have updated it to match either todo followed by either a space or `:` or match any of the other alternatives followed by a whitespace boundary.